# sorting 2nd column and then 3rd column using sort with negative values

Tags: linux, sort

I have date like the following.

```
random check/1 -0.02
random check/1 -0.05
random tell/1 -0.01
random tell/2 -0.02
random checking -0.00
```

I tried sorting for 2nd column and then 3rd column.
I used `sort -n -k2,2 -k3,3 file`. but it didn't gave the output I am looking for.

output should be:

```
random check/1 -0.05
random check/1 -0.02
random checking -0.00
random tell/1 -0.01
random tell/2 -0.02
```

and then I want to uniquify it. so the final output should be link

```
random check/1 -0.05
random checking -0.00
random tell/1 -0.01
random tell/2 -0.02
```

basically, its sorting 2nd column and then 3rd column, and uniq 2nd column, so I see only worst numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`sort -nk3,3 file | sort -uk2,2`

Answer (score 1):

```
sort -k2,2 -k3,3n | awk '$2!=s;{s=$2}'
```

Sort the data on the second field and then the third field numerically. Use awk to print the first occurrence of the second field (If the second field is different to the saved value then print the line, then save the second field).